# Adding MongoDB to React application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose

I have created a simple todo List app using ReactJS through create-react-app.
Each todo I add is pushed to an array called todos as shown below.

```
    state = {
    inpVal: '',
    todos: [],
  }

onInputSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //console.log('event fired');
    const newTodo = {
      value: this.state.inpVal,
      completed: false
    };
    const todos = this.state.todos;
    todos.push(newTodo);
    this.setState({ todos: todos, inpVal: '' })

  }
```

I want to add this todos array to a mongoDB. I have very less information about it.

Tried searching on google but a lot of different ways were showcased. I am not able to wrap my head around it.

Please suggest a way/steps to achieve this task.

Comment: React is for the frontend only. It is executed in the users browser. You need a backend as well. The backend will access the database. There are a lot of different ways to create the backend, e.g. with node.js and express, ASP.NET, PHP, ...

Comment: Create an api to access the DataBase. Client-side apps should not be attempting to update databases directly

Comment: @DanielHilgarth..If I add a node.js backend with express for routing and also create a mongodb schema using mongoose, how do I get each todo task from the frontend to the backend?

Comment: To get the data to the backend you can use axios

Comment: you can use localStorage